# How to use environment variable for Ansible shell's creates?

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

I am using the built-in [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) module, and want to use an environment variable inside the `creates` arg.

Something like the following:

```yaml
- name: Run pyenv install of Python 3.10.7
  shell:
    cmd: |
      exec $SHELL
      pyenv install 3.10.7
    # Is something like this possible?
    creates: $PYENV_ROOT/versions/3.10.7
```

My questions are:

- Is something like this possible?
- Would it expand the environment variable from the Ansible control node or Ansible target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible and the ansible way of doing this would be

```
- name: Run pyenv install of Python 3.10.7
  shell:
    cmd: |
      exec "{{ ansible_env.SHELL }}"
      pyenv install 3.10.7
    creates: "{{ ansible_env.PYENV_ROOT }}/versions/3.10.7"
```

In this case, the variable will be from the managed node (target). Provided `gather_facts` is set to true.

To use the values from the control node, use [`lookup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9_ja/plugins/lookup/env.html)

```
    creates: "{{ lookup('env','PYENV_ROOT') }}/versions/3.10.7"
```